# Git Clone returns "RPC Failed Curl 56 failure when receiving data from the peer"

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, git-clone

I have attempted to clone a Git repository from a Git GUI, Git bash, and Visual Studio and they all return the same error:

> RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer.
> Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
> CloneCommand.ExecuteClone

This is a brand new machine with fresh install of VS2017 professional.

I have tried setting the http.postbuffer but nothing makes any difference. I have rebooted and reinstalled vs2017 and git multiple times and nothing seems to make any difference. I have disconnected from VPN, hardwired to internet (112mbs download speed) so not sure where to look next

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default (Windows Defender and Windows Firewall)?  Also, please [see the Git FAQ}(https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) about why you should not set `http.postbuffer`.

Comment: I was able to clone "smaller" projects but the two "bigger" projects give me the RPC Ffailed; curl 56 error. So it "seems" to be related to the amount of data it needs to pull down and not firewall settings?

Comment: Yes, and if your antivirus or firewall is trying to snoop on the contents of your encrypted connections, it can often fail to handle large streaming content when fetched or pushed, which is why I asked.  Are you using a non-default antivirus or firewall?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this exact error message when attempting to clone large repos. Smaller repos worked fine.

Turned out it was caused by a corporate security app. If there is a corresponding service/agent running locally, it may have a function allowing you to disable it temporarily. Otherwise, you may need to talk to your admin to see if they can temporarily disable it or create an exception for Git.